# Can a ClickOnce application be published on Ubuntu?

Tags: .net, deployment, ubuntu, clickonce

I have built an application and this is published on a Windows server using ClickOnce. The clients go to the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator), can download and run the application.

The client is now changing their servers to run Ubuntu. Can a ClickOnce application be published on a server running Ubuntu?

The version of Ubuntu is 8.10., and I am using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and C#.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure can - any file or web server can host a ClickOnce app. 
However you will need to configure the correct MIME types on the web server

- .application => application/x-ms-application
- .manifest => application/x-ms-manifest
- .deploy => application/octet-stream

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for the reply. Those MIME types are for the IIS. I wasn't sure that you can run IIS on Ubuntu. I haven't used Ubuntu too much, so don't have much experience. What web server does Ubuntu use?

Thanks

Comment: No idea about the webserver Ubutu uses - probably Apache. Configure the server to associate the MIME types with the file extentions, and ClickOnce will work. IIS or Apache - MIME is for the client

Comment: The MIME types are for the documents.  You have to set them in IIS if you use IIS.  But you want to use Ubuntu.  so whatever HTTP Server you are using on Ubuntu, must have those MIME types set.

Answer (score 9):

Simply add the following to the .htaccess file in your web root (Apache2 Ubuntu)

```
AddType application/x-ms-application application
AddType application/x-ms-manifest manifest
AddType application/octet-stream deploy
AddType application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument xps
AddType application/xaml+xml xaml
AddType application/x-ms-xbap xbap
AddType application/x-silverlight-app xap
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're trying to use [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29), in which case:

> Is it possible to support ClickOnce on Linux? 
>   Yes - but there's still a lot of work required before doing so.
>
> Is ClickOnce the best way to distribute applications/updates? 
>   I'm not sure - but popularity != superiority so...
>
> *From http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2004-September/023224.html*

Comment: Nope - the server changed.  The clients remain Windows.